# Do not center Placeholder in TextInputLayout vertically

Tags: material-components-android, material-components

I am using Material Components 1.1.0. On a `TextInputLayout` I removed the background and left-aligned the placeholder and text by setting the `paddingStart` of the `EditText` to zero.

This gives me the following result:
[image]
Note the large distance between the Placeholder and the bottom line.
When actually typing text, the distance between the text and the bottom line is much smaller:
[image]
I want the Placeholder to have the same distance from the bottom line as the real text. How can I do this?

Used style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/textInputLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="textInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/transparentWhite</item>
</style>
```

Used `TextInputLayout`:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text_contract_partner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Stackoverflow"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You can try to reduce the space using paddingBottom and paddingTop in your TextInputEditText.

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried that and it does not work as one would expect \:

Comment: In my experience you can't obtain the same distance from the bottom line with or without text, you can only reduce it.

Comment: Why do you want a hint's default position to be as low as a text? You can try to extend the component and make your own behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the component and write your own behaviour. @Gabriele Mariotti is a grand master in Material Design, and I think, he is right. You can [ask](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues) for this feature.

This is a bit ugly solution, it has no animation due to toggling between hints.

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_end"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_start"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:hint="Stackoverflow"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/text_contract_partner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Stackoverflow"
         />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

text_contract_partner.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        textInputLayout.isHintEnabled = true
    } else {
        if (text_contract_partner.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            textInputLayout.isHintEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

1) Unfocused state with empty text:

[image]

2) Focused state with empty text:

[image]

3) Focused state with text:

[image]

4) Unfocused state with text:

[image]